# Вывод данных в Php

Tags: php

Есть форма в которой пишется номер телефона. Есть скирипт на php.

```
<?php
$a = explode(" ", $_POST['number']);
$operator_arr = array();
foreach($a as $number){
  $operator = substr($a[0],1,3);
  switch($operator){
    case '916':
    case '910':
    case '915':
    case '917':
      $operator = 'mts';
    break;
    case '926':
    case '925':
      $operator = 'megafon';
    break;
    default:
      $operator = 'unknown';

  }

if(!isset($operator_arr[$operator])){
  $operator_arr[$operator] = array();
}
$operator_arr[$operator][] = $number;
}

?>
```

Так вот как мне из этого массива вывести на экран "Ваш оператор mts, ваш  8916909090". Номер указан как пример. 
Помогите я только начал изучать Php! Спасибо!

Comment: Привет! ну по твоему коду у меня выводит не фига. Может я че-то не так делаю?

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в Вашем коде нужно исправить

```
$operator = substr($a[0],1,3);
```

на

```
$operator = substr($number,1,3);
```

и выводить можно так:

```
foreach ($operator_arr as $operator => $numbers) {
    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        echo "Ваш оператор ". $operator . ", ваш номер " . $number . "<br>";
    }
}
```